# Memorization software with prioritization

Tags: windows, educational, language

I'm trying to learn the constructed language Lojban, so I'm trying to find the right memorization software to do it.

I really would like one that has some sort of prioritization feature so I can prioritize words that are used more frequently. So far, I've found FullRecall and Anki, but neither of them seem to have this feature I'm looking for.

OS: Must be able to run on Windows 7 64-bit.

Price: Ideally free, but I'm willing to pay $20 or more if there's nothing else that fits my requirements.

Additional features: I don't need multimedia features, but would be nice if it used something like the [spaced repetition](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Spaced_repetition) technique (versus, for example, simple flash card software).

Comment: Anki will prioritize based on your answers